# JSONP not giving any response

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonp

Following is my code :

```
$.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                       alert("xhr="+xhr+"  status="+status+"   Error="+error);
                     },
                     success: function(jsonp) { 
                       alert("success");
                     }
      });
```

Url contains php file located on external server where I did `echo json_encode($array);`

Response is shown in firebug net tab but alert showing the following error :

**xhr=[object Object]  status=parsererror   Error=Error: jQuery17209610263814778152_1338375769339 was not called.alert is not showing success**

Comment: What happens when you paste the URL to the file producing JSONP directly in your browser?

Comment: @N.B. : it showing content in format of json

Comment: @N.B.: It showing following response : `[{"destination":"Dallas Texas United States","country":"United States"},{"destination":"Dallas XXX XXXX States","country":"United States"}]`

Comment: why is the datatype jsonp, the server code doesn't seem to pad the json in any way

Comment: @Esailija:  if I give there json only then the response is not coming in net tab

Comment: @Kunal true but in `JSONP` you also need the server to output the `padding`, not just the `JSON`

Comment: @Esailija : can you please explain it to me

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works

Comment: @Esailija : so how I get the response is there any way or not

Comment: @Kunal try the code in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode( $array ) . ");";
```

Comment: I want to develop application using javascript and HTML only. not want to use php code there

Comment: @Kunal right, in your question you said that `Url contains php file located on external server where I did echo json_encode($array);`. That is wrong because it's not `JSONP`, my answer changes it to `JSONP`.

Comment: thanks...but I only want to take a data from php file not to use it in my code.

Comment: This is the part where I stab myself repeatedly with a fork until I die

Comment: :-) I am also trying it from 4 days

Comment: @Kunal and you will keep trying it forever until you give up or change the server to output `JSONP` instead of `JSON`

Comment: so whats the solution for it?

Comment: The solution is to change your server to output `JSONP` instead of `JSON`. `echo json_encode($array);` outputs `JSON`. My answer outputs `JSONP`.

Comment: but how can I change output to JSONP

Comment: @Kunal why are you even trying to use JSONP? Do you even know what the difference between JSONP and JSON is? You also say you don't want to use PHP code, yet you're using it. It's hard to help if you don't want to **understand** after being helped.

Comment: @Kunal change the line `echo json_encode($array)` to `echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode( $array ) . ");";`

Comment: @Esailija : Actually I can't modify that php code thats why I want the solution without modifying it

Comment: @Kunal you cannot solve this without modifying the php code. You'd either need to modify it to output `JSONP` or output `CORS` headers. Either way you need to modify it and there is no other solution unless you find a security hole in browsers (You won't, just trying to be thorough).

Comment: As per your instruction I changed the php code to `echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode( $array ) . ");";` but when I alerting it showing null data in success.

Comment: @Kunal cool, was the response from server `jQuery17209610263814778152_1338375769339(null);` ? or the like

Comment: @Esailija : No no..thanks..solved it..actuly it was the problem of my $array variable.